# Google Chrome is not saving my breakpoints

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am using the Sources tab of the Google Chrome Developer tools to debug JavaScript, but Chrome is not saving my breakpoints after I restart my Gulp server. The breakpoints save when I refresh the page. When I restart the server, any JS file that I have open is closed and all of the breakpoints are removed. I have to add them back in every time.

My coworkers have the opposite problem. Some of them complain that old breakpoints persist that they no longer care about. Is there a setting in Chrome that allows breakpoints to persist after my code is changed and Gulp server is restarted?

Comment: I think this is a problem with your builder. Could you provide more information on how your final JavaScript files are generated? And do you use "map" files?

Comment: I think you may be on to something. I've asked others on my team to check one more time whether their breakpoints persist, and they said that they are having issues too. We will look into our builder.